# How to serialize object to JSON string using classes from "org.json" package?

Tags: java, json

I've tried to find any useful example to solve this easy task, however, nothing really helpful was found. I'm at the beginner level in Java and I definitely need some help.

I have two simple Java classes:

```
private class FMList {
    public List<FMItem> items = new ArrayList();
    public long size = 0;
    public int dirs = 0;
    public int files = 0;
    public String path = "";
}

private class FMItem {
    public boolean is_dir = false;
    public String[] ascii = {};
    public String name = "";
    public String mode = "";
    public long size = 0;
    public long mtime = 0;
    public boolean ext = false;
    public String cache = "";
}
```

My application (applet) creates an instance of `FMList`, sets data to object properties, and finally serializes the object to JSON string.

First, I tried [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. Simple `new Gson().toJson(fmList)` did the job perfectly, however my applet failed to start giving exceptions that Gson library has somewhat like security problems. Meanwhile, the applet was signed and all AccessController's were set.

Then, I tried to use classes from [JSON official website](http://www.json.org/java/). There are no exceptions anymore but that simple `new JSONObject(fmList).toString()` gives `{}` only. I understand that it should be used somehow in a different way.

*What is the right way to serialize this simple object to JSON string using classes from `"org.json"` package?*

Thank you for help!

Comment: Two answers both point out that the library operates on getters.  Is it feasible for you to just add the getters to your objects?

Comment: @phatfingers However, there is a documented method with specifying names of the properties and it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For field access like you are using (not get/set methods) you have to specify them:
[http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String[])](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

You either use the JSON Writer or "Stringer" (write to stream or create String) to not get a pretty printed json.

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONWriter.html

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONStringer.html

Update: Also the class can't be private with the simple org.json lib.
This works fine:

```
public class Main {
    public static class FMList {
        public long size = 0;
        public int dirs = 0;
        public int files = 0;
        public String path = "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new JSONObject(new FMList(), new String[] { "dirs", "files" }).toString());
    }

}
```

Produces: `{"files":0,"dirs":0}`

Changing to private class produces: `{}`

Comment: Hm... To specify, you mean something like that: `new JSONObject(fmList, new String[] { "items", "dirs", "files", ... }).toString()`?

Comment: I tried, and that doesn't seem to work: the same output `{}`.

Comment: Try without the `items` in that list once and see if that works.

Comment: That's because your class is private.

Comment: Yes! I've already got the point. Now I try to add gets to both classes, since without gets my serialized `items` looks like `[{}, {}, {}, ...]`. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: I can not get it to run on Android.
On Android the JSONObject expects JSONObect as obj (not a general java.lang.Object). I tried extending my Class from it, no syntax issues anymore but I get an empty {} as result. names is correct, everything is public, classes are static.

Answer (score 0):

The JSONObject expects to use the getters but your classes are only using public variables instead of the getters:

```
JSONObject(java.lang.Object bean) 
      Construct a JSONObject from an Object using bean getters.
```

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

Understood that you are looking specifically for serialization using the `org.json` package, but if you are open to other libs, Xstream is really easy to use for XML-related tasks, such as JSON serialization. Here is a JSON tutorial: http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html.