# Kotlin-Android serialize json without using third party library

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, codable

is there any solution other than `Moshi, Gson, KotlinX-Serialization` to `serialize` json in `Android`? We should not add anything to build.gradle while using technology. We should not download a library from here.

Is there a method on `Android` just like `Codable` on `iOS`? Also, I think how we should do this part is important since `Converter` will be passed when using it with `Retrofit`.

Does anyone have experience and advice on this subject?

Comment: Well... all of those libs are open source you can always [look at their source code](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization). In Android there's the implementation of JSON objects in the `org.json` package which, if I am not mistaken, comes with the framework. You'd have to do the parsing yourself, just like with Codable on iOS. If you want samples, there [are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12738097/2684) [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10674182/2684) of examples.

Comment: Why not use a third party? You aren't allowed to use any third party? You know `RetroFit` is a third party too right?

Comment: I'm building an android library and I don't want to use a third party library. I guess we won't be using retrofit either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) for that.

```
val json = JSONObject("""{"some":"json"}""")
```

However, easiest is to use one of the third party frameworks you mentioned to do this.